# lua debug hook causing race condition?

Tags: debugging, lua, hook

I wanted to report some debug information for a parser I am writing in lua. I am using the debug hook facility for tracking but it seems like there is some form of race condition happening.

Here is my test code:

```lua
enters = 0
enters2 = 0
calls = 0
tailcalls = 0
returns = 0
lines = 0
other = 0
exits = 0

local function analyze(arg)
    enters = enters + 1
    enters2 = enters2 + 1

    if arg == "call" then
        calls = calls + 1
    elseif arg == "tail call" then
        tailcalls = tailcalls + 1
    elseif arg == "return" then
        returns = returns + 1
    elseif arg == "line" then
        lines = lines + 1
    else
        other = other + 1
    end

    exits = exits + 1
end

debug.sethook(analyze, "crl")

-- main code

print("enters = ", enters)
print("enters2 = ", enters2)
print("calls = ", calls)
print("tailcalls = ", tailcalls)
print("returns = ", returns)
print("lines = ", lines)
print("other = ", other)
print("exits = ", exits)

print("sum = ", calls + tailcalls + returns + lines + other)
```

and here is the result:

```
enters =        429988
enters2 =       429991
calls =         97433
tailcalls =     7199
returns =       97436
lines =         227931
other =         0
exits =         430009
sum =   430012
```

Why does none of this add up? I am running lua 5.4.2 on Ubuntu 20.04, no custom c libraries, no further messing with the debug library.

Comment: Can you make your example fully reproducible by filling in some real code where you have "-- main code"? It shouldn't be all of your real code, but rather just enough to make the problem happen.

Comment: Also, when you say none of this add up, what do you mean? We don't have your code, so can't say what you'd inspect instead of the numbers you see.

Comment: I was thinking that this is independent from the rest of the code. enters, enters2 and exits should all have the same value, no matter what. And the sum of the branches which count individual events should also be the same.

After being stuck at this for half a day, the solution occurred to me 10 minutes after asking on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem...

The calls to the print function when printing the result also trigger the hook, which only affects the results that have not been printed yet.

Comment: So stop the hook before with: ```debug.sethook()``` - Also i suggest to call that before you set the hook. Only to be safe that no other hook function is present and working.

Comment: Don't pin me down on it but I think sethook clears any previous hooks. sethook(f, "r") will even unhook sethook(g, "c").
I've just concluded that from one instance when I observed that happen but maybe there's more to it.